# ¿Por qué obtengo el error "HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled" al intentar hacer una petición Retrofit desde un Fragmento?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, mvvm

No entiendo por qué me tira el error *`HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Canceled`* cuando hago una llamada desde un Fragmento. Si hago la llamada desde MainActivity, el código funciona.

Este es el código en `ViewModel`:

```
fun initialSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest) {
    _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Loading
    viewModelScope.launch(coroutineDispatcherProvider.IO()) {
        try {
            val result = getSyncUseCase.execute(syncRequest)
            _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Loaded(SyncItemUiState(result))
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            _uiState.value = SyncUiState.Error(error.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Desde el UseCase llamo a esta implementación del Repositorio:

```
override suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
    var syncResponse = SyncResponse(SpannableStringBuilder(), emptyList())
    if(syncRequest.type==1) {
        val syncNetwork = syncFactory.create(Source.NETWORK).getSync(syncRequest)
        if(syncNetwork.allToday.isNotEmpty()) {
            syncResponse.allToday=syncNetwork.allToday
            syncResponse.dataForView=syncNetwork.dataForView
        }else{
            val syncFirebase = syncFactory.create(Source.FIREBASE).getSync(syncRequest)
            syncResponse.allToday=syncFirebase.allToday
            syncResponse.dataForView=syncFirebase.dataForView
        }
    }
    return syncResponse
}
```

Este es el código para manejar la llamada a la API:

```
override suspend fun getSync(syncRequest: SyncRequest): SyncResponse {
    val todayAll=todayApi.getTodayAll("all")
    val syncResponse= SyncResponse(SpannableStringBuilder(),todayAll)
    return syncResponse
}
```

Poniendo puntos de depuración, nunca pasa de esta línea, en ese punto el flujo se cancela:

```
val todayAll=todayApi.getTodayAll("all")`
```

No es problema de la API, todo este código, llamado desde `MainActivity` funciona.

Y este es el código para la llamada a la API:

```
@GET("today/{thePath}")
suspend fun getTodayAll(@Path("thePath") thePath: String?): List<Today?>
```

El ViewModel está capturando este error:

> kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Job was cancelled;
> job=SupervisorJobImpl{Cancelling}@c05b47

No entiendo por qué tengo este error cuando hago esta llamada desde un Fragmento:

```
val syncRequest = SyncRequest(0, 1,false,false)
syncViewModel.initialSync(syncRequest)
```

Y la misma llamada funciona bien en MainActivity. Estoy probando el código en el emulador. En el Fragmento, el código se llama cuando el usuario hace clic en un botón.

¿Alguna idea de por qué falla en un contexto y en otro no? No veo quién cancela la petición, ni dónde ocurre eso.